# mysql column naming conventions for foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Lately I've been thinking about what's a better name for foreign keys, either `user_id`, or `id_user` style.

Personally I think `id_user` style is better for handling within database (db queries) where it's clear from the first three characters that the column is containing ID.

On the other hand I find `user_id` style more suitable e.g. with use of HTML autocomplete fields where there are two input fields; one `name="user"` for text, the other `name="user_id"` for his ID; which makes it easier to recognize that they belong to each other because they both start their name by defining what the content will be about.

What do you think?

Comment: I should use `user`.

Comment: I would have to say this question is off topic. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Different cms use different convention. Use what suits your best

Comment: @S.Visser: `user` is a reserved word and should not be used as column (or table) name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer user_id but I think it doesn't really matter as long as you stay consistent and not mix them up so you keep your overview structured and readable.

Answer (score 0):

As @randomizer correctly suggested, don't mix it, choose one - that is the stone rule.

I would suggest:

If you will name all columns with prefix e.g. `user_columnName` , do it with id too.

If I would use `id_user` I would avoid postfixing and named other self-columns without post/prefix.

I personally like using ID everywhere, where is some primary-ID and `id_*` elsewhere where it's referenced, because that way it is clear that ID is the primary id of the current table and `id_*`s are foreign keys to IDs in `*`s .